# Allowing my Amazon Cognito users to upload to specific folder on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I want to give my mobile users the ability to upload directly to S3 using Amazon Cognito.

**If I replace the following:**

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::blinq-test/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
```

**with:**

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::blinq-test/*"]
```

all works good and the mobile user can upload data to the bucket.
The problem is that I want each user to have his own folder.

Here is my Role policy that attached to the pool Authenticated users:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::blinq-test"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::blinq-test/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the above - I get the following error:

```
04-13 11:27:35.754  23269-24251/com.blinq I/AmazonHttpClient﹕ Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x98cdf200: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x98cdf200: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:765)
        at com.android.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:70)
        at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:116)
        at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:44)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink.write(HttpConnection.java:291)
        at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:116)
        at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:131)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.write(UrlHttpClient.java:155)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.createConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:143)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:60)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:361)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:211)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3838)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1512)
```

What am I missing?
perhaps my mobile code should somehow direct it to that folder?

it looks like the following:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
context, "us-east-1:bea10200-deed-cafe-8c8c-c1b1884410aa", Regions.US_EAST_1);

Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
final String accessToken = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();
logins.put("graph.facebook.com", accessToken);
credentialsProvider.withLogins(logins);

TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
String keyname = "test";
transferManager.upload("blinq-test", keyname, file);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **answer** is within the upload process itself:

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
String keyname = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId() + "/test";
transferManager.upload("blinq-test", keyname, file);
```

make sure that the upload is made to the **sub folder** of that user